# Calling destructor when replacing object

Tags: c++

I have a variable that holds an object. Now I assign a different object to this variable. Will the original object be destructed and when?
Example function:

```
{
    myclass a();
    myclass b(); //create 2 objects
    a = b; //copy b
} //leave scope, both copies of b will be destructed
```

Comment: `myclass a();` is not an object definition, it's a function declaration. You want `myclass a;`.

Comment: Ah right. Or myclass a(1); for constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will the original object be destructed

Yes. All automatic variables are destroyed automatically.

> and when?

Automatic variables are destroyed at the end of the scope.

> when replacing object

Assignment doesn't "replace" the assigned object. Assignment sets the value of the object.

---

P.S. In your example code, you have no objects. You've declared two functions and attempted to assign one of them (assigning a function is ill-formed).

Comment: So if I understand that correctly, the destructor will be called 2 times with the values of b but never with the values of a. So if one of the values is a pointer to an object that is deleted in the destructor, it will not work because the object of b is deleted twice (and a's not at all)

Comment: @Apache00 To avoid these problems there is [the rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three): you carefully write overloaded move/copy constructor/assignment to not leak or double delete anything.

Comment: @Apache00 The destructor will be called with both the value of `a` and value of `b`. But given the assignment, those values are the same (unless the assignment operator does unconventional things). `So if one of the values is a pointer to an object that is deleted in the destructor, it will not work because the object of b is deleted twice (and a's not at all) ` If that's what the destructor and assignment operator do, then they are badly designed.

Comment: I mean the original values, before the assignment. In the end a and b will both hold the original value of b and destruct with that, I mean

Comment: @Apache00 OK. Regardless, what happens in assignment operator depends on what the assignment operator does. They can be user defined.

Answer (score -1):

Your objects will be destroyed at the end of the scope. When you assign b to a(assuming objects are declared correctly, by this I mean use just myclass a; without braces), a will not be destroyed, just its value will be changed. Also, you need to overload the assignment operator.

Comment: What happens if I don't overload the assignment?

Comment: Any default or something, what would it do?